# How does JetBrains PyCarm IDE put files into directories outside of ~/ despite being run without sudo?

Tags: security, root-filesystem

PyCharm is a lovely Python IDE by JetBrains that can be downloaded [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/). I have downloaded the free community edition, extracted (with sudo) it into `/opt/jetbrains/pycharm` and run (without sudo) `/opt/jetbrains/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh`. As soon as I have run it it has created a link to itself at `/usr/local/bin/charm` (I used tho think this is impossible to do without root privileges) and a .desktop file at `/usr/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop`). How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities for how this happened.  The first ones that come to mind are

1. It could be invoking `sudo` on your behalf without you knowing it.  Do you have `sudo` setup to work without a password?
2. It could be owned by the user root with the setuid bit set. That would cause the program to run with root permissions.
3. You could have permissions on `/usr/local/bin` set to allow write access by your user

Without knowing more about the situation it's difficult to say exactly how it was able to do what it did but I would start by checking these three.

Comment: It was the first one. I have never actually met an application that would exploit this so I have started to believe they can't do it :-)